# How to add a .vb class file to an ASP.net project

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I'm fairly new at ASP.netand picking up someonelse's code, please be kind :)

The project that I created and the one I copied do not see the functions in my datalayer.vb class. Is there something special in ASP.net (add a reference?..etc) that I need to do to be able to have intellisense and for the functions to be seem in in my aspx pages?

Please advise
Thanks
Cin

Answer (score 0):

In your solution viewer, right click on the project, go to add > new item > and select class from the new item dialog.

Comment: Here's what I tried, I added my class to the App_code, then app_data,then bin in all 3 I got cant find the file error. At the root I still get Name 'GetMember' is not declared (this is a function in my class. When I build/rebuild the site I get the error.  Do I need to somehow compile the VB file?
PS: I'm building a whole new project using this file, is there a reference I might need to add to use classes?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of web project, you may need to either place the file in a special `/App_Code` folder or compile the project in Visual Studio and place the new dll file created in the `/bin` folder.

Comment: Joel,What do you mean by depending on the kind of web project? I'm using Visual STudio 2008 and its asp.net 2.0